# Bluestacks - LAN Access

Tags: lan, bluestacks

I downloaded Bluestacks on macOS and I am using an app that has an HTTP Server. The app is showing the url to access the settings: 10.0.2.15:7474 which is not accessible from Mac. How I am supposed to access bluestack's network?

Comment: So you have an app running in Bluestacks on your Mac and you want to access it from a different computer over the LAN or from the same computer it is running inside? What is the IP address of your Mac?

Comment: My mac's IP is 192.168.10.241